# MacOS Sonoma says no disk burner found

Tags: audio, optical-drive, sonoma

LG "Slim Portable DVD Writer" Model GP55EX70 plugged in with blank CD.  Tried to burn a playlist to CD and MacOS said "No supported Disk burners found"

https://www.devicemag.com/lg-slim-portable-dvd-writer-on-mac/ says drivers would be automatically loaded when the drive is plugged in.  But whoever wrote that page is goofy—he says if the Mac doesn't recognize the drive I should reformat it "ExFAT" (!?!)

I don't recall whether I ever burned a disk with this drive.  I do know that I used it to import dozens of audio CDs and to watch at least one DVD, but all on earlier OS versions.

Neither Disk Utility nor Finder shows the drive connected.  It's on a USB-C to A converter which has worked fine with other USB-A peripherals.

Comment: Did you insert a blank CD/DVD into the drive?

Comment: Yes.  If it wasn't blank, Finder should have shown the contents.

Comment: Try inserting a known good medium inyo the drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. The drive itself is faulty.
2. MacOS no longer includes drivers for writing to this drive.

I would try to find a Windows box or older Mac with an earlier OS, and see if it will burn on there.

Burning is still supported on my Apple SuperDrive, but I don't know whether different drivers would be required for third-party drives.

Comment: https://www.lg.com/us/burners-drives/lg-gp55ex70-ultra-slim-external-dvd-drive claims compatibility. Besides trying on a different computer, using another cable/another USB port might also help.

Comment: @nohillside Yes, I think there would be more reports if Apple had removed support for third-party burners, though I imagine that disk burning may be considered 'antiquated' by Apple at some point...

Comment: disk burning antiquated?  I hope not!  There is not yet any physical storage medium thinner or easier to mail than an optical disk.

Comment: Didn't have any other computer to try it on, so I took it to a shop where the guy tried it on a non-Mac and concluded it was dead.  But they could not sell me something to replace it.  Checked electronics departments of two large stoeres and found blank CDs & DVDs but no drives.  Employee in the first one pointed me to SSDs when I said "optical drive" and again when I said I have to make a CD.  Asking at the second store why they sell CDs and nothing to write them with, the guy showed them hiding behind hard drives, no price labels.  Nearly the same model is mine, and it works.

Comment: So the answer is #1—something failed in the drive since the last time (previous time) I used it.  Working replacement is nearly identical and cost only 26 US dollars.